# How to access locale value from config in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, next.js

I need to get the `i18n.defaultLocale` from the config of my Next.js app. It seems like a trivial task, but I can't find anything about reading the config of Next.js app. Is there any built-in object to use, or should I just import the object exported by `next.config.js`?

Comment: I suggest you have a read through [Accessing the Locale Information](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#accessing-the-locale-information) documentation.

Comment: Hi @juliomalves thank you! If you'd like to hey some points for your hint, don't hesitate to post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than directly accessing the value from your `next.config.js` file, Next.js provides a couple of ways to access the locale information, depending on where you need it.

On the client, from a React component, you can use the `useRouter()` hook to access locale information, including the `defaultLocale`.

```
const { defaultLocale, locale, locales } = useRouter()
console.log(defaultLocale)
```

On the server, when pre-rendering pages with `getStaticProps`/`getStaticPaths`/`getServerSideProps`, the locale information is provided in the context passed to those functions.

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ defaultLocale, locale, locales }) {
    console.log(defaultLocale)
    // ...
}
```

`getInitialProps` also exposes a `router` object from its context which can be used to retrieve locale data.

```js
Page.getInitialProps = async ({ router }) => {
    const { defaultLocale, locale, locales } = router
    console.log(defaultLocale)
    // ...
}
```